# when I sort the record in jQuery dataTable. All the record goes disappear from the table, in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

> I am implementing jQuery dataTable in ASP.NET MVC project. Data is showing in the table based on the item selected in the drop down list.
> When we sort the data based on the any column then data in the table goes disappeared or it showing the previous selected item data.
> **HTML Table**
> This is HTML Table in which we showing the data

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
        <thead class="bg-primary">
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th width="20%">Name of Air Operator</th>
                <th width="20%">ID</th>
                <th width="20%">Type</th>
                <th>Submitted</th>
                <th>Approved</th>
                <th>Rejected</th>
                <th>Pending</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="OpeatatorDetails" class="table-bordered">
           
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Dropdown**

> This is dropdown in which item is binded

```
<div class="container mt-5" id="operatorwiseContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <select class="form-control" id="ddlOperatorwise">
                <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
                <option value=""> ALL </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**onchange event of dropdown**

> code for onchange event occurs

```
        $('#ddlOperatorwise').change(function () {
            var aopID = $(this).val();
            ShowData(aopID);
        });
```

**ShowData code  method to show the data in table**

> This method call using ajax when drop down item change

```
function ShowData(aopID) {          
            var aopID = aopID;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/t_operation_request/NewAOI',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { aopID: aopID},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#OpeatatorDetails').empty();
                    var j = 1;
                    var rows;
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                       rows +="<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + j++ + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + name + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.id + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + " " + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.submitted + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.approved + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.rejected + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.pending +"</td>"
                            + "</tr>";

                    });

                    $('#OpeatatorDetails').append(rows);
                    $('#myTable').dataTable();


                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something went wrong!");
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Now is the time for you to do some debugging.  Are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?  In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  In the `success` callback, when you use the browser's script debugger, what is the observed runtime value of `data`?  Stepping through the code in the debugger, what specifically happens?

Comment: Add the data directly to the DataTable: [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())